# Joomla Documentation public beta

Tags: discussion

So Stackoverflow's Documentation has recently gone into a public beta state.

The Joomla tag has been created so we need to get a few more people to commit to it:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/joomla

Once we get 5 commiters, we'll be able to start documenting :)

Comment: I was trying to create installation manual for beginners. should we use Joomla docs or some other docs??

Answer (score 2):

The entire [Stackoverflow Documentation project](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) has been shut down.

I think the sensible place to route Joomla volunteers is to [Joomla! Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/).

The documentation could really benefit from some more attention.

Comment: It's a shame but I can understand why. Wasnt really used and too late in the lifecycle when there are other resoruces out there already. Official docs are Joomla's own so makes sense to send people that way

Answer (score 0):

pls contribute to the Goalkicker to make a robust Joomla Docs/Tutorial:

> http://goalkicker.com/